# Bootstrap-datetimepicker generating strange static month number

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap-datetimepicker of tarruda, when I choose date, calendar picking day and year fine but generating some strange number like '54' for month, where month value shouldn't be greater than 12, even after choosing different month previously generated number is not changing.

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxoysa0y/) in which the issue is the same as mentioned above.

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  allowInputToggle: true,
  autoclose: true,
  pickTime: false
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code:

> var dateFormatComponents = {
>
> .....,
>
> MM: {property: 'UTCMonth', getPattern: function() {return '(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\b';}},
>
> mm: {property: 'UTCMinutes', getPattern: function() {return '(0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])\b';}},
>
> ....

So the right format is:

```
***"dd/MM/yyyy"***
```

For more details you may take a look too [momentjs format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

The updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxoysa0y/1/).

The snippet:

```js
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
  allowInputToggle: true,
  autoclose: true,
  pickTime: false
});
$('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: "hh:mm",
  allowInputToggle: true,
  autoclose: true,
  pickDate: false,
  pickSeconds: false
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>


<form class="" id="course-enroll-form" action="/lessons/dashboard/{{lesson.id}}" method="post">
    <p>Propose day</p>

    <div id="datepicker" class="input-append date">
        <input id="datetime" type="text" name="date" class="form-control" required="required"
               placeholder="Date: dd/mm/yyyy"/>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-calendar" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    </div>
    <p>Propose time</p>

    <div id="timepicker" class="input-append date">
        <input type="text" name="time" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Time: hh/mm"/>
    <span class="add-on">
                                        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-time"></i>
                                    </span>
    </div>
    <h6 id="course-enroll" class="bt-course">
        <button type="submit" name="button">Click to book</button>
    </h6>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dd/MM/yyyy` instead on `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
  allowInputToggle: true,
  autoclose: true,
  pickTime: false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uxoysa0y/2/